# How can I read the numbers from a text file, display thenumbers in a listbox control then display the following Data?

Tags: c#, parsing

I'm trying to read numbers from a text file, each number is on it's own line. Display how many numbers there are, and, add those numbers. This is my code so far.

```
private void readFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
        openFileDialog1.ShowDialog();
            filePathReader = openFileDialog1.FileName;

            //declare the variable to read the file
            string numbersFromFile;
            infile = File.OpenText(filePathReader);

                //reads the contents
                while (!infile.EndOfStream)
            {
                //get the numbers
                numbersFromFile = infile.ReadLine();
                //add numbers to the listBox
                numbers.Items.Add(numbersFromFile);
            }
            numbers.Items.Add("How many numbers the file has and the Total of the random NUmbers");

            //closethe file
            infile.Close();
            //Here I am supposed to display the total of the numbers there is a way to turn text data into int data
            //and the total numbers the user wanted..say there are a total of blah random numbers
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //display error message
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
```

Comment: What's your problem?

Comment: I generated a user specified number of Random numbers  and saved them in a text file. I then created a click event, where I open that file and display how many numbers the file has, and the total of those numbers in the list box.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you are facing with this code @LivingstonSeagull? Did you debug the code to check what's wrong with it?

Comment: Nothing is wrong with the code, I need a way to read the numbers from the text file, display how many numbers were generated by the random number generator, and display the total numbers in the list box. I got the point where it displays all of the random numbers in the list box.  This form has a list box to display said data and a button to handle the event.

Comment: `Nothing is wrong with the code,`  Then why the question? `numbers.Items.Count` should give you the number of numbers you read from the file.

Answer (score 1):

First of all, if you need to read entire file , read entire file in 1 shot.

```
var path = "myfile.txt";
var allLines = File.ReadAllLines(path);
var count = allLines.length;
var sum = allLines.Select(s=> int.Parse(s)).Sum();
```

Answer (score 0):

> Display how many numbers there are,

```
var numbers = new List<int>();
numbers.Add(int.Parse(numbersFromFile));
int count = numbers.Count;
```

> and, add those numbers

```
int sum = numbers.Sum();
```

Make sure to import `using System.Linq`